# Why do these dp units render twice as thick in the same Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Below I have some xml to generate a scale-able fork for generating ranking ladders. This xml is used several times in the same layout. However, the dp lines scaled with the screen height seem to randomly vary in actual pixel height when used.

Why is this? Why would a 1dp height unit on the same screen return both 1 and 2px on the same device?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="8dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#e7000000"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="#e7000000"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="8dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#e7000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="8dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#e7000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you share screenshots

Answer (score 1):

It's a rendering bug with the Android Emulator. No issues were found on physical devices.